# Wordpress and Plugin Development

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm currently in the process of building an existing website I built into Wordpress. I'm making good progress but I've hit a hitch. I am well aware that Wordpress has thousands of plugins already there that can be used but I've decided I would like to give it a go and try build my own. I came across an article on the internet that was a good starting part - but I'm getting an error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I am using the following tutorial posted on this website - http://starkod.net/build-wordpress-contact-forms-plugin-save-to-db-and-send-email/

So far following the steps in the tutorial I've been able to make the plugin display in the plugins menu - activate the plugin - upon activating the plugin the custom table is added to the database to store any records, the menu item for the contact form responses is visible in the wordpress dashboard but after that I get the following error -

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
>
> The error says its based on line 73 of the code

```html
//if you want to have both logged in and not logged in users submitting, you have to add both actions!
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'starkod_admin_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_add_foobar', 'starkod_admin_add_foobar' );
function starkod_admin_add_foobar()
{

global $wpdb;
$data=array(
'name' =&amp;amp;gt; sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']),
'email' =&amp;amp;gt; isset($_POST['email'])?sanitize_email($_POST['email']):null,
'msg' =&amp;amp;gt; sanitize_text_field($_POST['msg']),
'time' =&amp;amp;gt; current_time('mysql')
);
$table_name=$wpdb-&amp;amp;gt;prefix.'starkod';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
// send Email for admin
wp_mail( get_option('admin_email'), 'starkod Contact Form',
'Name : '.$data['name']. ' phone : '.$data['phone'].' email : '.$data['email'].' The message: '.$data['msg'].' Time : '.$data['time'] ,$headers);
if($wpdb-&amp;amp;gt;insert( $table_name, $data))
{
$_SESSION['message'] = "Your Message received , thanks ";
}
else
{
$_SESSION['message'] = "there's problem try again please";
}
//redirect back to where user was comming
wp_redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
//request handlers should die() when they complete their task
}
```

Line 73 of code starts here -

```html
'name' =&amp;amp;gt; sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']),
```

If anyone could help me out to fix this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the **provided code** is that you should have `>` on every place that you currently have `&amp;amp;gt;`. Like so (I "beautified" it a little):

```
//if you want to have both logged in and not logged in users submitting, you have to add both actions!
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'starkod_admin_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_add_foobar', 'starkod_admin_add_foobar' );
function starkod_admin_add_foobar() {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = array(
        'name'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['name'] ),
        'email' => isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] ) : null,
        'msg'   => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['msg'] ),
        'time'  => current_time( 'mysql ')
    );

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'starkod';
    $headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
    // send Email for admin
    wp_mail(
        get_option( 'admin_email' ),
        'starkod Contact Form',
        'Name : ' . $data['name'] .
        ' phone : ' . $data['phone'] .
        ' email : ' . $data['email'] .
        ' The message: ' . $data['msg'] .
        ' Time : ' . $data['time'],
        $headers
    );

    if ( $wpdb->insert( $table_name, $data ) ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Your Message received , thanks ";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "there's problem try again please";
    }
    //redirect back to where user was comming
    wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    //request handlers should die() when they complete their task
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Kaloyan - one last question - the records are adding into the database and to the wordpress dashboard - the timedate format in php my admin is YYYY-MM-DD any ideas how and where I could change this in the code from the tutorial to DD-MM-YYYY instead?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. :) According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time I believe you should change `current_time( 'mysql ')` to `current_time( 'd-m-Y' )`. Google "php date" for more info about the date format.